# DigitalOcean Loadbalancer behavior Kubernetes TCP 443

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

Currently I've this Load Balancer Service on my Kubernetes Cluster.

```
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)            AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP      [HIDDEN]       <none>            443/TCP            44h
load-balancer   LoadBalancer   [HIDDEN]       [HIDDEN]          443:30014/TCP      39h
```

This is my .yaml file config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: load-balancer
spec:
selector:
    app: nodeapp
type: LoadBalancer
ports:
    - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 3000
    name: https
```

For some reason DigitalOcean does not setup the HTTPS instead if leaves it as TCP 443. And then I've to manually go to DigitalOcean and change TCP to HTTPS and create the let's encrypt certificate. How can I make Kubernetes create a load balancer using HTTPS on port 443 instead of TCP 443.

Answer (score 0):

According with their [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/how-to/configure-load-balancers/#ssl-certificates) you need to add additional annotations like that:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: https-with-cert
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-protocol: "http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-algorithm: "round_robin"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-certificate-id: "your-certificate-id"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx-example
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 80
```

How to add SSL certificate: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/load-balancers/how-to/custom-ssl-cert/

Answer (score 0):

A Service of type Load Balancer will create a Layer 4 type LB(Network LB), with awareness of only the IP and Port.

You will need Layer 7 LB(Application LB), that's application aware.

So, to enable HTTPS, you will need to manage via an ingress.